# Are there any examples of a random variable with infinite second moment and finite variance?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

The theorem in my notes says that:

> If $|X - a|^\alpha$ has expectation for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and any $\alpha > 0$, then $|X - b|^\beta$ has expectation for any $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and any $\beta$ such that $0 \leq \beta \leq \alpha$.

So if we know that the second moment $E \, X^2$ is not finite while $\operatorname{Var} X$ is, are $E\,X$ and $E(X - E(X \mid Y))^2$ finite? Is there any example or counter-example for this case?

**Update:**
From the theorem, it seems that $|X−a|^\alpha$ can have expectation for only a set of $a$ (say $a\in A$) at a specific $\alpha$. So is it possible that $|X−E\,X|^2$ has expectation while $X^2$ doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

Every random variable with finite variance has finite second moment.  Variance is only defined for random variables with finite first moment, and as you probably know,
$$E [X^2] = \operatorname{Var}(X) + E[X]^2.$$

Comment: I think this equation only works if they are finite. Anyway, just from the theorem, it seems that $|X - a|^\alpha$ can have expectation for only a set of $a \in A$ at a specific $\alpha$. So is it possible that $|X - EX|^2$ has expectation while $X^2$ don't?

Comment: @Broccoli: The equation I cite is valid as long as $EX$ is finite; $E[X^2]$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ don't have to be.